# Create New Big Object Record in Marketing Cloud Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, big-object

After sending an SMS or Email to a customer using a Marketing Cloud Journey, we would like to create a record in Service Cloud that details the content of the communication as well as the date/time sent. For storage purposes, we would like to store this information in a Big Object. Because Big Objects are not accessible using the "Create Object" activity in a Journey, we need a custom work around. Is there a known solution to this use case?

Comment: Is real-time a requirement in your use case ? or a 1-day or 1-hour delay for example can still be feasible ?

Comment: Am not too sure but the AMPScript function CreateSalesforceObject may work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB way to achieve this. You would need some other code/config running to get it done.
Examples could be
- create a standard object record in SFDC using the custom object activity in Journey Builder and then having a trigger create a record in the big object. You could then clean these temporary records up on a daily basis.
- using Contact Update activity you could check on an hourly basis then using a SSJS activity in an Automation you could call the SFDC API to directly create the Big Object record.

Evidently, both ways are hacky at best. Your best bet is a custom activity based on something like Heroku which can be designed to do just about whatever you want but it's not a small amount of development so most people wouldnt go down that path
Hope it helps
Doug